# Is there a way to move by screen lines in vim?

Tags: vim

When editing files in vim, it is a small annoyance that when I move lines with j and k, it moves by file lines, rather than screen lines like other editors. With my own files, I can deal with this by automatically wrapping to a certain length in the vim options, but this is no good for files from others. Is there a vim command to either temporarily toggle the treatment of lines to screen lines, or alternate commands for moving that use screen lines?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can move around the screen lines by using `g` in front of the commands:

```
gj
gk
g$
g0
g^
```

You can also map the original commands to the `g` commands like this:

```
:map j gj
```

`j` moves by screen lines now.

Comment: +1 for the `map` suggestion. Although I personally dont want to do it _all_ the time, I'd like to use it when I want it.